# Batch Script to find a files inside all Sub Folders

Tags: batch-file

I have the multiple images in sub folder, I don't know how many folders are there. I want to Batch script to find listed names in all the folders and copy the images to destination folder. I tried below script but am getting file not found error.

```
@echo off

rem Find files and copy files

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "SourceBaseFolder=D:\System backup\picture batch file\Test\15oct2015"
set "TargetBaseFolder=C:\OutputFolder"

if not exist "%SourceBaseFolder%\*" (
    echo %~nx0: There is no folder %SourceBaseFolder%
    set "ErrorCount=1"
    goto HaltOnError
)

cd /D "%SourceBaseFolder%"

if not exist "FileNames.txt" (
    echo %~nx0: There is no file %SourceBaseFolder%\FileNames.txt
    set "ErrorCount=1"
    goto HaltOnError
)

set "ErrorCount=0"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%N in ("FileNames.txt") do (
    for /R %%J in ("%%N*") do (
        set "FilePath=%%~dpJ"
        if "!FilePath:%TargetBaseFolder%=!" == "!FilePath!" (
            set "TargetPath=%TargetBaseFolder%\!FilePath:%SourceBaseFolder%\=!"
            md "!TargetPath!" 2>nul
            if exist "!TargetPath!\*" (
                echo Copying file %%~fJ
                copy /Y "%%~fJ" "!TargetPath!" >nul
            ) else (
                set /A ErrorCount+=1
                echo Failed to create directory !TargetPath!
            )
        )
    )
)

:HaltOnError
if %ErrorCount% NEQ 0 (
    echo.
    pause
)
endlocal
```

Can any one fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your quoting strategy is not right. change `set SRC_FOLDER="C:\Source"` to `set "SRC_FOLDER=C:\Source"`, `'DIR %SRC_FOLDER% /A:D /B'` to `'DIR "%SRC_FOLDER%" /A:D /B'`,  `'DIR %SRC_FOLDER%\"%%D\%%F" /A:D /B'`  to `'DIR "%SRC_FOLDER%\%%D\%%F" /A:D /B'` and all similar. You are searching the folder name `"c:\source"` _yes, with quotes_

Comment: Thanks @elzooilogico am serching for files from 'FileNames.txt' for images

Comment: @elzooilogico I have update the code please check it

Comment: @LotPings, the use of `%~nx0` seems to be a valid reference to the running script itself! Gold Pearl I have taken a look at your updated script, however you have not updated the problem relative to that version. Can you please tell us what the problem is with the updated script we now see.

Comment: @Compo You are right - not may day ;-) Too much multitaslking.

Comment: Did you want to search only pictures ? or any files with any extensions ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're trying to get to work seems excessively convoluted

I believe something similar to the following should do what you want

```
FOR /F %%G IN ('dir /a-d /s /b "D:\System backup\picture batch file\Test\15oct2015"^|findstr /I /E /G:"D:\System backup\picture batch file\Test\15oct2015\FileNames.txt"') DO (
copy "%%G" "C:\OutputFolder"
)
```

To ensure the filename matches are exact, all filenames in filenames.txt should be preceded by backslash, e.g.

```
\filename1.file
\filename2.file
```

You can easily generate such a file within a batch file, if necessary